# Enqueued Stylesheets Effecting Admin Styles

Tags: theme-development, wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, css

I'm building a custom theme for a client and I've been adding stylesheets incorrectly for a while, so I decided to do it the correct way :-).

However, when I add the stylesheet to my `functions.php` file like so:

```
wp_enqueue_style('theme-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/all.css', array(), false , 'all');
```

It also is applying to the Wordpress Admin panel. My link colors and fonts change, and there are some layout issues as well.

If I enqueue it inside of a function like this:

```
function theme_styles(){
        wp_enqueue_style('theme-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/all.css', array(), false , 'all');
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles' );
```

It does not change the admin panel at all, which is good. So my question is, when researching and reading about how to enqueue stylesheets no articles mention adding styles to a function. Scripts, yes, but not styles. What is the correct way to do it to avoid changing my admin styles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
function theme_styles(){
    /*
     * This if() statement is unnecessary, as wp_enqueue_scripts
     * doesn't fire on the admin pages.
     * if( is_admin() ) {
     *   return;
     * }
     */
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'theme-styles', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/all.css', 
        array(), 
        false,
        'all'
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles' );
```

### References

- [`is_admin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/)

Also, note that the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) hook is used to enqueue *both* scripts and styles.

Comment: `is_admin()` is not necessary here

Comment: @PieterGoosen Agreed, running the function without the `is_admin()` and it works just fine.

Comment: You're right. I'm not entirely sure what I was thinking there.

Answer (score 3):

Enqueueing styles within a function as you have done is the standard best practice for WordPress, whether you are building a theme or creating a child theme. And as mentioned, you can enqueue both styles and scripts from within one function, http://marker.to/65CMY3.